# Twitter Login Integration in angularjs and Java

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to implement twitter login in my website.I am able to open a child window on click of twitter login button , which then redirects to twitter login page and upon scuccessful authentication gives the oauth key , using which i am able to pull data for that user.
    How can i close child window and let parent refresh itself?Remember it should happen only on user authentication verification.Parent window should somehow watch the child window url and if url changes to 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize', then close child window and refresh parent.


    Essentially, how can i wait until url changes to a given url in angularjs?
    Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by closing the page where i get twitter response from server( using javascript-onload )and then i call login() to let user login automatically.It is working fine as of now but if user clicks on close button after opening twitterwindow and without filling in his credentials,it again submits data for login resulting in error response.

In order to solve this, i need to know that is there a way to differentiate between manually closing the browser vs closing it through window.close().It is live on the website [www.reviewmatters.com](http://www.reviewmatters.com) .Please help